# Umbraco partial view rendering issue

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco, partial-views

I currently have 2 pages using the same partial view on Umbraco and the code in question displays the breadcrumbs on each site to display the home page and the current page it's on. The original code below was working fine for the Europa page however it was giving a null exception for the Singapur page.

My code changes have sorted the null exception, however the Europa page now isn't displaying the 2nd part of the breadcrumb on the right that displays the current page it's on. But the Singapur page displays both breadcrumbs fine as it's suppose to.

Original code:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="@viewModelMenu.Home.Url">@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue ("Start page")</a></li>
            <li><a @(!viewModelMenu.IsCurrentContinent ? "href="+ @viewModelMenu.Continent.Url : null)>@viewModelMenu.Continent.GetGermanyPageTitle()</a></li>

@if (!viewModelMenu.IsCurrentContinent)
            {
                foreach (var parent in viewModelMenu.Parents)
                {
     <li><a href="@parent.Url">@(parent.GetGermanyPageTitle())</a></li>
                }
                <li>
                    <a>
                        @(Model.Content.GetGermanyPageTitle())
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My code changes that's now making the breadcrumb on the right not appear on Europa page but working fine for Singapur page:

```
<div id="infomation" class="content-position">
    <div class="breadcrumb">
        <ul>
@{
   var homeLink = viewModelMenu.Home.Url;
   var homeText = Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("Start page");

 <li><a href="@viewModelMenu.Home.Url">@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("Start page")</a></li>
var getPage = string.Empty;
string link = null;
if (!viewModelMenu.IsCurrentContinent)
 {
    if (viewModelMenu.Continent != null)
    {
        link = "href=" + viewModelMenu.Continent.Url;
        getPage = viewModelMenu.Continent.GetGermanyPageTitle();
    }
 }
}
  @if (!viewModelMenu.IsCurrentContinent )
            {
                foreach (var parent in viewModelMenu.Parents)
                {
                    <li><a href="@parent.Url">@(parent.GetGermanyPageTitle())</a></li>
                }
                <li>
                    <a>
                        @(Model.Content.GetGermanyPageTitle())
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Working breadcrumb:
[image]
Not working breadcrumb:
[image]
What I want my code to display on the Europa page just like it does for Singapur:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the IsCurrentContinent method is returning true for Europa, which means you're not getting anything other than the start node in the breadcrumbs.